# jQuery object is empty after dynamically creating it

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I want to add an event listener inside a class after creating the corresponding element.

In my event listener inside the `appendSelectedFilter` function I want to refer to the clicked element. Since I can't use `this` in this context I tried to create a jQuery object and parse it to the `resetThisFilter` function, but the object has a length of `0`.

What am I missing here? How can I parse the clicked object to another function?

```js
class RecipeFilter {
  constructor(filterkategories, response) {
    this.filterkategories = filterkategories;
    this.response = response;
  }

  appendSelectedFilter(filterItem) {
    let value = filterItem.children[0].children[0].value;
    let filter = `<div class="selectedFilter ${value}" ><span class="icon-pk-close"></span>${value}</div>`;
    if ($(".checked-filter").find(`.${value}`).length === 0) {
      $(".checked-filter").prepend(filter);
    }
    $(document).on("click", ".selectedFilter", () => {
      this.resetThisFilter($(`.selectedFilter .${value}`));
    });
  }

  var recipeFilter = new RecipeFilter(filterkategories, response);
  recipeFilter.renderFilters(filterkategories);

  $(document).on("click", ".filter-list-item", function() {
    recipeFilter.appendSelectedFilter(this);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accept the Event object as an argument to your arrow function, then you can use the `target` property of the event to retrieve the element which the user clicked on:

```js
appendSelectedFilter(filterItem) {
  let value = filterItem.children[0].children[0].value;
  let filter = `<div class="selectedFilter ${value}" ><span class="icon-pk-close"></span>${value}</div>`;
    
  if ($(".checked-filter").find(`.${value}`).length === 0) {
    $(".checked-filter").prepend(filter);
  }
    
  $(document).on("click", ".selectedFilter", e => {
    this.resetThisFilter($(e.target));
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats exactly what I was looking for!